# Regex to parse long urls

Tags: php, regex, url

I have this regex which works quite well but not in all scenarios for instance if I have a long url say "http://www.gob.cl/especiales/politicas-y-propuestas-de-accion-para-el-desarrollo-de-la-educacion-chilena/" it will only return me "http://www.gob." as part of the url

Here's my code

```
    $regexUrl = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regexUrl .= "([a-zA-Z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regexUrl .= "([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3})";  // Host or IP 
    $regexUrl .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regexUrl .= "(\/([a-zA-Z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regexUrl .= "(\?[a-zA-Z+&\$_.-][a-zA-Z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regexUrl .= "(#[a-zA-Z_.-][a-zA-Z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor 
    //if(preg_match_all("#\bhttps?://[^\s()]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#", $message, $matches1, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
    //$pattern = '/((https?|ftp)\:(\/\/)|(file\:\/{2,3}))?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)?)+)(\.)(com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|[a-z]{2}))([\/][\/a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)*([\/]?(([\?][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\=][a-zA-Z0-9\%\(\)]*)([\&][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\=][a-zA-Z0-9\%\(\)]*)*))?/';
    if(preg_match_all("/$regexUrl/", $urlMessage, $matches1, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
    {
      try
        {
            foreach($matches1[0] as $urlToTrim1)
            {
                $url= $urlToTrim1;
                echo $url;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $url="-1";
        }
    }
```

Can there be a generic regex which can parse all kind of urls.

Answer (score 2):

Your host-or-ip part of the regex

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3})"
```

does allow at maximum a single dot inside. Therefore "www.xyz.com" can never match.

I do not know what your specific requirements, but you may go with something like

```
"([^/?#:]+)"
```

for the host part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one for extracting all URLs from $text:

```
preg_match_all('#(https?://[a-z0-9\.\-_\#%&=/?;,!:~@\$\+]+)#iu', $text, $m);
```

It's on the assumption that a URL starts with https:// or http:// and then can have a sequence limited to a special set of characters.

Then I can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php on `$m` to get all the URL's details

Edit: Also, if you are parsing text, you might want to check for periods (`.`) and other punctuation at the end of the URL. I've noticed that humans may put a `.` at the end of the URL if the URL is at the end of the sentence for example like http://example.com.

So I do something like this:

```
 if (($url[$pos]==='!') || ($url[$pos]==='.')) { // probably do not want these chars at the end of a url!
    $url = substr($url, 0, $pos);
 }
```

Comment: +1. You can also use a lookbehind to force the regex itself to back off if the last matched character is one of the forbidden ones: `'#https?://[a-z0-9._\#%&=/?;,!:~@$+-]+(?<![.!])#iu'`

Answer (score -1):

How about you match everything beginning with http:// or https://

`((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))`

Comment: (1) `(?:http|https)` is needlessly verbose and inefficient; `https?` works just fine.  (2) `/` only needs to be escaped if you use `/` as the regex delimiter; there are many other options.  (3) Double escaping isn't necessary if you use `'` instead of `"` as the string-literal delimiter.  (4) Inside a character class, `.` doesn't need to be escaped and `|` is not an "OR" operator, it just matches a `|` (the "OR" is implied).  (5) `[/.]?` is pointless anyway, since `[^\s"]*` matches both those characters.  (6) There's no need to wrap the whole regex in `()`.  (...) I could go on... ;)

Comment: Well, it correctly matches the one example the OP provided.  You're okay if the URLs are always enclosed in double-quotes as they are in the text of the question, but I don't think that's what the OP meant to imply.  (But I'm wrong anyway: your regex also matches the `http://www.gob.` in `"http://www.gob."`, which is obviously incorrect.)